# What's the difference between counters and registers in TeX?

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

Why in plain TeX it says "New counters are allocated starting with 23, 24, etc.  Other registers are allocated starting with 10"? I want to know what's the difference between counters and registers in TeX. If anyone could enlighten me on this that will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all counters in plainTeX are registers!

New counters are allocated starting with 23, because the lower register numbers are already in use. From the documentation of plainTeX:

> ```
> % The following counters are reserved:
> %   0 to 9  page numbering
> %       10  count allocation
> %       11  dimen allocation
> %       12  skip allocation
> %       13  muskip allocation
> %       14  box allocation
> %       15  toks allocation
> %       16  read file allocation
> %       17  write file allocation
> %       18  math family allocation
> %       19  language allocation
> %       20  insert allocation
> %       21  the most recently allocated number
> %       22  constant -1
> ```

So most of the reserved counter registers are needed to manage the allocation of registers. And that is the reason why other types of registers does not need such a lot of reserved register. For other registers with ten reserved registers those reserved registers are for free temporary usage.

Comment: But how to explain `Other registers are allocated starting with 10`?

Comment: @Jiapan -- just rephrase the comment above the list as "The following counters (registers) are reserved:".

Comment: @Jiapan: Each register is of different kind and for a different purpose and counters, i.e. number registers are needed a little bit more — you need more of numbers for common tasks then other registers, such as boxes or tokens etc.

Comment: @Jiapan: Also, do not forget that plainTeX is just a bunch of macros over virgin TeX. If you create different set of macros you may perhaps need more box registers for your macros and leave only those above, say, `\box30` to users, whilst leaving them all the number registers — counters — above, say, `\count15`